# For a random variable $X$, what exactly does $-X$ and $X^n$ mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For a random variable $X$, what exactly does $-X$ and $X^n$ mean?

I have doubts about this, I hope you can help me

Comment: Bear in mind that a random variable is just a special type of function. So it would mean, in effect, the same it does for ordinary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a "positive" random variable, i.e., $\mathbf{P}[X>0]=1$, so in the same sense of a ordinary functions a "negative" random variable is $\mathbf{P}[-X<0]=1$. Similarly with definition for random variable $X^{n}$ with $n\in \mathbf{N}$.

**Remark:** As a function $X: \Omega \to [0;+\infty[$.